# How can I set linker options for a Cordova plugin?

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova, linker, phonegap-plugins

I am developing a Cordova plugin that uses a custom ios SDK framework. The framework depends on two binary libraries: `libcurl.a` and `boost.a`. Right now during development I install the plugin in a test application like this:

```
cordova platform add ios
cordova plugin add my.cool.plugin
```

The binaries are included in the framework and get copied to the project that installs the plugin. However, some linker options are missing. To get the project to build, I have to open xcode and perform two additional manual step:

```
open platforms/ios/MyCoolProject.xcodeproj/
```

First, I have to add the two libraries to **Link Binary With Libraries** section in **Build Phases**:

[image]

Second, I have to add two linker flags (`-lz -lstdc++`) to Other linker flags section of the project default target.
[image]

I certainly would like a `cordova add plugin my.cool.plugin` to be sufficient to install the plugin. So my question is, how can I automatically perform these tasks when the plugin gets installed?

Comment: Did you figure this out?

Answer (score 3):

for -lz -lstdc++ just add this in the plugin xml and it will work.

```
<framework src="libstdc++.dylib" />
<framework src="libz.dylib" />
```

Comment: the same way for `-lc++` it would be `<framework src="libc++.dylib" />`

Answer (score 0):

You can't set link flags (at the moment at least), however in this specific example the -lz actually just adds the libz.dylib. So to translate this to the Cordova plugin just add;

```
<framework src="libz.dylib" />
```